How do Eddy Current Brakes work without any change in area or magnetic field strength
Taking this as an example:

It is not apparent to me why moving the magnet around the plate, would cause the plate to move.
As far as I was taught, Faraday’s Law is denoted as:

where ε = e.m.f., Φ_B = magnetic flux, B = magnetic flux density, A = area through which flux passes.
I really do not understand how B or A would change in this example.
Here’s another example from Wikipedia where the disk is spinning this time:

B: magnet’s magnetic field, I: induced Eddy currents.
It seems to me like in all cases B and A are constant, which would give a 0 e.m.f., so I must be getting something wrong. The same “amount” of field lines seem to pass through the disks in both cases, so I really don’t know.
FYI. I am currently doing A-Levels, so please explain anything that would be bordering university level.
Here’s the mark scheme for the question that included the first apparatus:


